# How do I tell cromwell and womtool what WDL version to use?

Tags: cromwell, wdl

I find lots of references to how cromwell supports the development version of WDL.  I find people talking about running cromwell using the development version of WDL.

What I can not find anywhere is instructions on how to do this.

For example:

```
$ $CROMWELL_HOME/womtool --type wdl --type-version development validate My.wdl 
Error: Unknown option --type
Error: Unknown option --type-version
Error: Unknown argument 'development'
```

Whereas if I just call womtool, I get an error when trying to use the Directory keyword from WDL development:

```
$ $CROMWELL_HOME/womtool --type wdl --type-version development validate My.wdl 
ERROR: Unexpected symbol (line 9, col 5) when parsing '_gen10'.

Expected rbrace, got Directory.

    Directory   OutputDir
    ^

$workflow = :workflow :identifier :lbrace $_gen10 :rbrace -> Workflow( name=$1, body=$3 )
```

Update:

You must have every single file on the same version.  If you don't, you will get the error

```
ERROR: Finished parsing without consuming all tokens.

version development
```

Note: Using cromwell 65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [WDL specifications](https://github.com/openwdl/wdl/blob/main/versions/1.0/SPEC.md#versioning), the WDL version must be indicated in the WDL file itself by putting `version <insert_version_here>` on the first line of the file. If this line isn't present then the execution engine should consider the version to be draft-2.

eg.

```
version 1.0

workflow example {
...
```

In order to use the developmental version in cromwell, `development` should be used as version. This is mentioned in the [cromwell docs](https://cromwell.readthedocs.io/en/stable/LanguageSupport) under "Language Support" -> "Future Language Support":

```
version development

workflow example {
...
```

Comment: $ $CROMWELL_HOME/womtool validate My.wdl 
ERROR: Finished parsing without consuming all tokens.

version development